# Realizar un gráfico para un sensor binario en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Me gustaría saber si es posible crear un gráfico lo más parecido a este desde python:

Tengo 3 sensores que pueden ser cero o uno a lo largo del tiempo. Para cero sería rojo y verde si es uno.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo csv es de esta forma:

```
16:08:01;1
16:13:01;0
17:05:01;1
```

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pylab as pl  
import csv 
import matplotlib.dates as dates
def Grafico_escalera():
    formato = dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
    #entrada = open('historia_Presion_Cam_1_2019_09_17.csv') 
    historia_cama = open('historia_Cam_1_2019_09_19.csv' )
    tabla_cama = []  
    for fila in csv.reader(historia_cama,delimiter=';'):
        tabla_cama.append(fila)  
    historia_cama.close()  
    x_cam=[]  
    y_cam=[]  
    for fila in range(1, len(tabla_cama)):  
        #x.append(tabla[fila][0])
        x_cam.append(datetime.strptime(tabla_cama[fila][0], '%H:%M:%S'))
        y_cam.append(float(tabla_cama[fila][1].replace(",",".")))

    historia_pul = open('historia_Pul_1_2019_09_19.csv' )
    tabla_pul = []  
    for fila in csv.reader(historia_pul,delimiter=';'):
        tabla_pul.append(fila)  
    historia_pul.close()  
    x_pul=[]  
    y_pul=[]  
    for fila in range(1, len(tabla_pul)):  
        #x.append(tabla[fila][0])
        x_pul.append(datetime.strptime(tabla_pul[fila][0], '%H:%M:%S'))
        y_pul.append(float(tabla_pul[fila][1].replace(",","."))+1.1)

    pl.figure(1, figsize=(9, 6))
    pl.step(x_cam,y_cam)
    pl.step(x_pul,y_pul, 'r') 
    pl.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formato) 
    pl.xlabel('Hora')  
    pl.ylabel('Estado [Si/No]')  
    pl.title('Grafica Sensor de cama')  
    pl.savefig('grafica_sensor_cama_2.png', dpi=300)  
    pl.show()
```

Y me muestra el siguiente gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y tienen que aparecer también las etiquetas de texto que muestras, o sólo los colores? ¿Y en qué formato tienes guardada esa información? ¿En una lista? ¿Cómo se almacena en qué instante comienza y termina cada estado? ¿O sólo se almacena cuándo cambia de estado?

Comment: Con que aparecieran los colores me vale. Los datos los importo de tres archivos en csv con dos columnas, la primera es la fecha, la segunda el estado 0 o 1. Cada vez que cambia el estado añado una fila.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Carlos, no olvides marcar como aceptadas las respuestas que hayan resuelto tu problema (en esta y en tus otras preguntas), para evitar que estas preguntas sigan pareciendo "abiertas" cuando ya han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 3):

Para lo que sigue, utilizo pandas como contenedor de los datos. Es más sencillo con pandas leer csv, o generar datos aleatorios (como he hecho en mi caso). Pero no debería ser difícil de adaptar si no quieres usar pandas. Como mínimo, puedes inspirarte en algunas de las ideas que utilicé para la creación del plot, para el cual he usado directamente primitivas matplotlib y no pandas (que también puede generar gráficas, pero esta en particular no parecía fácil).

### Datos de ejemplo

Empecemos por generar algunos datos de ejemplo, por ejemplo tres sensores que llamé `cama`, `pul` y `foo`, que comienzan todos a la misma hora y cada uno de ellos, tras un tiempo aleatorio entre 1 y 10 segundos, cambia su valor de 1 a 0 y viceversa, para generar así 30 puntos para cada sensor. Cada uno de ellos se guarda en un dataframe Pandas separado

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from random import random

def mock_sensor(t_ini=datetime.datetime.now(), initial=1, delta=10, samples=30):
  t = t_ini
  v = initial
  for n in range(samples):
    yield t.time(), v 
    t += datetime.timedelta(seconds=random()*delta+1)
    v = (v+1)%2

cama = pd.DataFrame([t for t in mock_sensor()])
cama = cama.set_index(0)
pul = pd.DataFrame([t for t in mock_sensor()])
pul = pul.set_index(0)
foo = pd.DataFrame([t for t in mock_sensor()])
foo = foo.set_index(0)
```

Por ejemplo, el sensor `cama` comenzaría así:

```
>>> cama.head()
                 1
 0                 
 16:44:20.007007  1
 16:44:26.974624  0
 16:44:37.213397  1
 16:44:45.899440  0
 16:44:48.873387  1
```

Se ve que el índice del dataframe es el *timestamp* y la única columna que tiene (llamada "1" por defecto) tiene los valores booleanos del sensor.

### Gráfica

Pues bien, dados estos dataframes, la siguiente función genera un plot como el que buscas. Está comentada para que se entienda lo que va haciendo, pero siéntete libre de preguntar cualquier detalle adicional en comentarios:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def my_plot(sensores, names, figsize=(20,1)):
  """Genera el plot buscado a partir de los parámetros:
  * sensores: lista con los dataframes de cada sensor
  * names: lista de cadenas con los nombres de los sensores
  * figsize: tamaño en pulgadas de la figura resultante
  """

  # Calculamos el número de sub-gráficas a generar, y la hora de inicio
  # y de fin del plot completo (ya que cada sensor puede tener su propia
  # hora de inicio y fin)
  n_sensores = len(sensores)
  t_min = min(sensor.index[0] for sensor in sensores)
  t_max = max(sensor.index[-1] for sensor in sensores)

  # Creamos la figura y sus ejes
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
  ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])

  # Recorremos la lista de sensores y creamos la gráfica de cada uno
  for i, sensor in enumerate(sensores):
    offset = i+1      # Es la distancia vertical correspondiente al "1" para este sensor
    x = sensor.index  # El eje x son los tiempos
    y = sensor[1]     # El eje y son los valores 1 y 0

    # Comenzamos por rellenar todo de rojo (todo cero por defecto)
    ax.fill_between([t_min, t_max], [offset-1, offset-1], [offset, offset],  step="post", color="red")

    # Y ahora pintar los unos en verde
    ax.fill_between(x, [offset-1]*len(y), y-1+offset, step="post", color="green")

    # Una línea blanca para separar mejor los sensores
    ax.plot([t_min, t_max], [offset]*2, 'white')

  # Etiquetar el eje y
  ax.set_yticks([i+0.5 for i in range(n_sensores)])
  ax.set_yticklabels(names)
  ax.set_xlim(t_min, t_max)
  plt.show()
```

Si lo usamos así:

```
>>> my_plot([cama, pul, foo], ["Cama", "Pul", "Foo"])
```

genera la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Resultado]

Aunque puedes variar el parámetro `figsize()` para hacerla más estrecha o más alta:

```
>>> my_plot([cama, pul, foo], ["Cama", "Pul", "Foo"], figsize=(10,2))
```

[image: Otra]

## Actualización

Una vez el usuario me ha facilitado una muestra de cómo son sus .csv, podemos sustituir la función `mock_sensor()` que "emulaba" la lectura del csv mediante generación aleatoria de datos, por una función que los lea de verdad.

En este caso es muy sencillo leer el .csv directamente con pandas, sin más que indicarle que el separador de columnas es el punto y coma, que la columna 0 del csv será nuestro índice, que las cadenas contenidas en esa columna son en realidad marcas horarias, y que el csv no tiene cabeceras que den nombre a las columnas. Es decir:

```py
def read_my_csv(filename):
    return pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", index_col=0, parse_dates=True, header=None)
```

Esta funcíón se usa directamente así:

```py
def Grafico_estados():
    cama = read_my_csv('historia_Cam_1_2019_09_19.csv')
    pul = read_my_csv('historia_Pul_1_2019_09_19.csv')
    foo = read_my_csv('historia_Pul_1_2019_09_19.csv')

    print(cama.info())
    print(pul)

    plot_states([pul, cama], ["Pul", "Cama"], figsize=(10,1))
```

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda, la verdad es que con lo que me has dicho casi lo tengo,  el tema es que solamente me muestra un gráfico, puede ser porque los ficheros no tienen el mismo número de líneas?

Comment: Tendría que ver cómo son tus ficheros ¿puedes subirlos a algún sitio y darme el enlace?

Comment: Hola, He subido los archivos y el progama a la siguiente dirección: https://mega.nz/#F!PaBUBIZD!501g-oRkuwRMOmRFSj_kaQ

Comment: Hola, ya está solucionado. Era una tontería, no tenía  indexado todas las lineas debajo del for. Perdón por las molestias. Ahora corrijo la pregunta inicial con la respuesta. Gracias por todo.

Comment: @Carlos He actualizado la respuesta para mostrar cómo leer el CSV desde pandas, que es más sencillo (y más rápido) que hacerlo con el csv.reader.

Comment: última pregunta, :-) como puedo guardarlo en png. escribo fig.savefig('logs/Grafico_estados_' + Fecha +'.png', dpi=300) y no salen los ejes ni las letras, gracias!!!